# Python - Catch error with specific code

Tags: python, error-handling

in code I have this error

```
raise ClientError(response_data['data']['error'], response.status_code)
ClientError: (300) corrupt or not supported.
```

How to catch error 300?

```
try:
    somestuff

except ClientError:
    if error = 300:  # ?????
        print 'catched'
    else:
        just end the program
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Will appreciate an upvote/answer select if i answered your question.

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation, but I accepted your answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import errno

try:
  ..
except ClientError as serr:
    if serr.errno == 300:      
        raise serr
```